# Trying to convert Raw image(Bayer format) to jpg/png image in Python

Tags: image-processing, python

I am using the Sony Low-light image dataset from the paper Learning-to-see-in-the-Dark. I am trying to convert Raw image (bayer pattern in arw format) into a jpg/png. I used an online tool that gives a very dark jpg for a short exposure image and I have also used Python rawpy library to read and process the raw image. The resulting image from rawpy is shown below:

[image: **enter image description here**]

Rawpy gives a brightened image for a low-light image, which is not desired. I was expecting a dark rgb image. How can I get a dark rgb image in jpg format using rawpy?

Comment: Could you show me the way you convert ARW images to PNG ones.  I am also working on the paper (Learning to see in the dark). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve your problem?

Otherwise, I can introduce you an utility software tool (free to download) to convert any raw images to jpgs. I converted all long/short .RAF and .ARW images (in Learn to see in dark) to jpgs in just 30 sec. Unlike rawpy, it doesn't change (brighten) the images.